# C++ : auto variable deduction differs range for loop vs a normal for loop for multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's the following:

```
int ia [3][4] =  {
                        {0, 1, 2, 3},
                        {4, 5, 6, 7},
                        {8, 9, 10, 11}
                     };
```

1. Normal assignment:

   ```
   auto p = ia;
   ```

   This is understandable.
   Array **ia** returns pointer to its first element which is the 1st row of 4 elements (batches of 4 elements).
   p has int (*)[4]. Doing a p + 1 will point to the next batch of 4 elements.
2. Using range for:

   ```
   for (auto row : ia) {
           for (auto col: row)
                   cout << col << " ";
           cout << endl;
   }
   ```

   Why **row** is not int (*)[4] since each loop it's returning batches of 4 elements just like the previous example?
   Instead it is int *.
   When I hovered mouse over **row** variable it gives me int *..

Thanks

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion it's `int*`? Because I can't reproduce such a deduction.

Comment: What is `arr1`?

Comment: @StoryTeller It got decayed by the `const auto`.

Comment: The first is not a normal `for` loop.  A *normal* for loop would be: `for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row){ for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column) { cout << ia[row][column] << "\n";} }`

Comment: @T.C. - I would have suspected it's passing `ia` to `std::begin` is what would have decayed it first. Does `std::begin` have an overload that can accept a `int(*)[4]`? Or is it `int(&)[4]`?

Comment: @StoryTeller No, but there's no `std::begin` call, implicitly or explicitly, in this example. (And it wouldn't have decayed anything anyway.)

Comment: @T.C. - [Beg your pardon](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc3f14440ca18a5f)?

Comment: @StoryTeller Bogus compiler error message.

Comment: @T.C. - Or a bogus implementation. Regardless. The OP's confusion seems to stem from not understanding `row` is in fact initialized from a dereferenced `int(*)[4]`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Nah, that's a pretty decent "normal" for loop, basically expressed in terms of iterators.

Comment: Basic understanding is name of ia return int   (*)[4] and not int *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range-based `for` loop takes each array element and uses it in a declaration or expression derived from your given initializer in each loop round. An array element has type `int[4]`, so for an invented variable `int __elem[4]` representing the current range element, your loop body effectively says:

```
const auto row = __elem;   // __elem is int[4]
```

Now this should look familiar: the array expression on the right decays to a pointer to its first element, which has thus type `int`.

If you want to avoid the decay, you need to bind a *reference* instead:

```
const auto& row = __elem;    // row is int(&)[4]
```

Putting this back into your range-based loop, you want:

```
for (const auto& row : ia) {
    for (const int& cell : row) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it  decay? Without decay it would have  been int (*)[4]  .. sorry new to c++ .. What is decay?

Comment: @yapkm01: In many circumstances, a value (lvalue or rvalue) of array type becomes a prvalue of type pointer-to-element whose value is the address of the first array element. This is called "decay". It's extremely fundamental, as it enables basic things like subscripting: Given `int a[3]`, we can say `a[i]`, which is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, and here `a` decays to `&a[0]`, so that pointer arithmetic applies to the array *elements*. Without decay, the expression `a + i` would make no sense. Decay also lets us write `for (auto* it = a; it != a + 3; ++it) use(*it);` to iterate the array.

Comment: if you put auto row= ia; or const auto row = ia; and hover your mouse of variable row .. you'll see that it's int (*)[4]. Why would it differ using a range for loop?

Comment: @yapkm01: That's perfectly consistent with what I just said. `ia` is an array of `T`, and it decays to a `T*`. (You just need to fill in `T = int[4]`.) You may be in too deep here; try simpler types first until you wrap your head around the idea of arrays. Arrays of arrays work just the same, but it's easier to lose yourself in the complexity.

Comment: @yapkm01: Let's try again: `T a[7]; auto it = a;` Now `it` is an `T*` with value `&a[0]`, right? So far so good. Now do the same thing, but replace `T` with `int[13]`: `int b[7][13]; auto it = b;`. Again `it` is the decayed pointer to the first element, `&b[0]`. `b[0]` is an `int[13]`, so its address has type `int(*)[13]`.

Comment: Int (*p)[4] = ia; you can do p +1 which essentially points to the &p[1]. That is a pointer arithemetic  ..  It now points to index 1. Range for in each loop return a element which is an array of 4 int.  So having (**)[4] Is relevant saying this pointer now points to an array of 4 elements. Next loop of p will return next batch of array of 4 elements.

Comment: Point is ia return batches of 4 elements so shouldn't it be int (**)[4]?

Comment: I have revised my original question which i hope provides clearer picture of the confusion i am having

Comment: @yapkm01: Maybe [read this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) until it makes sense?

Comment: This statement 'Each element of the sequence, in turn, is dereferenced and assigned to the variable with the type and name given in range_declaration.' sounds like step 1) sequence return is (*)[4] step 2) deference it .. hence final type is int *. Did i get this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153977/discussion-between-yapkm01-and-kerrek-sb).

Comment: Thanks. I think i get it now. I think in the 'range for' on arrays, each loop it returns the address of an array element of size 4 which essentially is an int *.